# How come my constraints get messed up when I try to round corners using UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to round corners of my label and button using UIBezierPath. The problem is that when I use it, it seems to ignore my constraints that tell the label and button to extend all the way to the end of the view. How can I get the constraints to work with this? Here is with and without the UIBezierPath code:

[image: With]

[image: Without]

**Code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pathEULALabel = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:EULALabel.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.TopLeft, .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        let maskLayerEULALabel = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayerEULALabel.path = pathEULALabel.CGPath
        EULALabel.layer.mask = maskLayerEULALabel

        let pathAcceptButton = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:acceptButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        let maskLayerAcceptButton = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayerAcceptButton.path = pathAcceptButton.CGPath
        acceptButton.layer.mask = maskLayerAcceptButton
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the frame of your view changes after viewDidLoad is called. The size of your rounded corner views you are seeing is probably the width of your view in your storyboard.

Try putting your code in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead. This seems like a more appropriate place for the code to live.

Alternatively, you could look into making an @IBDesignable UIView extension that lets you round the corners of any view, straight from your storyboard. That's the 'nice/best' option, although this is fine too.

Comment: I put the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews and it worked like a charm. Thanks!